# How to do Data cleaning with multiple text files

Tags: python, pandas, text-files, data-cleaning, logfile

I have directory with log files.
So, for reading and concatenating i'm using following commands:

```
filenames = glob('*.log')
df = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames
```

Every log files looks like this:

```
Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25    Batch no: 3459  Date: 2020-01- 3


Time       IS current   IS volt.    Dee RF  Magnet  Probe   Coll-l  Foil Target Coll-r  Vacuum
05:25:39    0   0   0.0 0.0 130.85  0.1 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.1 2.2E-06
05:25:40    0   0   0.0 0.0 130.85  0.1 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.1 2.2E-06
05:25:41    0   0   0.0 0.0 130.85  0.1 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.1 2.2E-06
05:25:42    0   0   0.0 0.0 130.85  0.1 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.1 4.2E-06
```

For data cleaning and transformation, I'm using:

```
fline=open("abc.csv", ).readline().rstrip()
```

Output:

```
'Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3451 \tDate: 2020-01- 2,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3452 \tDate: 2020-01- 2,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3453 \tDate: 2020-01- 2,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3454 \tDate: 2020-01- 2,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3455 \tDate: 2020-01- 2,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3456 \tDate: 2020-01- 3,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3457 \tDate: 2020-01- 3,Tracer: (1) 18F-Nb25 \tBatch no: 3458 \tDate: 2020-01- 3'
```

after that, for splitting:

```
fline = fline.split('\t')
```

and finally:

```
df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv',  sep='\t', skiprows=[0,1,2,3], names=['Time','IS current','IS volt.','Dee','RF','Magnet','Probe','Coll-l','Foil','Target','Coll-r', 'Vacuum'])

df['Date'] = fline[2].replace("Date: ","")
df['Batch'] = fline[1].replace("Batch no: ","")
```

But `Date` and `Batch no` shown in csv as per first log file read.....
need help to show date and batch number in correct way.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format the code and output in your question as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). This will help people to better understand your code, what you're trying to achieve, and what the problem is.

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected output? What do you mean by correct way?